# What is the difference between compiler and IDE?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between compiler and IDE? Please explain me. because i am new to this terms.

Comment: You could have seriously googled IDE, and Compiler, and read up on this yourself.  This is really lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IDE is an "Integrated Development Environment."  It happens to contain a minimum of three things:

- A Text Editor (albeit more complicated than Notepad, but you *can* use Notepad if you're feeling sadistic)
- Code Completion (this is the most powerful thing about using an IDE over Notepad: it can suggest auto-completions or jump you to definitions of classes, methods, or properties)
- A compiler

Often it will have more than this, such as Christer comments below, but this is pretty much the bare minimum: "the ability to modify the code and the ability to run it contained within the same application."

A compiler, then is this:

- A program that takes as input raw code and outputs an executable program file, dll, or other similar binary.

Comment: You say "three things" like an IDE serves only those three functions. An IDE may contain other functionality too like for example a debugger, GUI editor, version control, etc...

Comment: You are correct @Christer, I meant "at least three things."  You could probably get away with a bare minimum of two (text editor + compiler) but I suspect that that would not be much more of an environment than Notepad and a separate compiler executable.